# How to convert csv string to float?

Tags: python, csv

I have `export.csv` file, with data

```
name,total
candy,10
ice cream,15
potatoe chips,20
```

when i read the .csv file with this code

```
with open('files/export.csv','r') as file_csv:
    read= list(csv.reader(file_csv))
    for row in read:
        print(row)
```

Turns out that the data in the total column is a string data type not a float. I want the output be like this:

```
"name","total"
"candy",10
"ice cream",15
"potatoe chips",20
```

So I can sum and take the total column data.

Comment: The `float` builtin can convert a string to a float as long as it is in Python's literal float format.

Answer (score 2):

To convert the 2nd field into `float`s, the following should work for you:

```
import csv

with open('files/export.csv','r') as file_csv:
    read = list(csv.reader(file_csv))
    for i, row in enumerate(read):
        if i > 0:
            row[1] = float(row[1])
        print(row)
```

Though do note, that here, we have to skip the first row (header) to apply the conversion only to the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read it with pandas. Give really strong support to csv files.

**Code**

```
import pandas
pandas.read_csv('files/export.csv')
```

**Results**

[image: Results]